# Map Request and Response in Apache Camel Jetty Component

Tags: java, jetty, apache-camel, proxy-server

I am trying to create an HTTP proxy server using Apache Camel Jetty Component. 
Following is my code -

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:8080?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
            .process(new Processor() {

                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    HttpServletRequest req = exchange.getIn().getBody(
                            HttpServletRequest.class);
            })
            .to("http://www.google.com:80?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
            .process(new Processor() {

                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

                    HttpServletResponse res = exchange.getIn().getBody(
                            HttpServletResponse.class);


    });
```

I need to maintain a mapping of response with each request i.e. I need to find the corresponding request for the received response. But, i am not able to think how I can do that in a multi threaded environment.

Please help me.

Comment: Not at computer at the moment but you should be able to do the following.In your process method save the request to a file. Generate a  GUID for the request and append that GUID to the request and also set it on the header. Then when the response comes back you should be able to marry it up.

Comment: OK, I will try this. But tell me If I will send some extra header in request, it is guaranteed that I will get that header with same value in response ?

Comment: Yeah as far as I have experienced

Comment: During the investigation, I found one thing that I am getting same exchangeId in both process() methods and this exchangeId is different for each request/response combination. So, is this exchangeId unique at all times ? and can I use this for mapping request and response ?